# How to remove an entry from JSON using dataweave?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I have a json like below:

```
{   "queueNumber": "123",   "field": "name",   "UserId": [     12,     12,     34   ],   "test": [     {       "objectName": "test",       "uniqueNumber": "123456"     }   ] }
```

I have a function which iterates over each key and removes it if matches. But, I also need to check for the value. I tried with the below function it works perfect when it comes to check and remove the key. But, it is giving an exception when I am checking for the value.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var keyToRemove = "queueNumber|name|uniqueNumber|cur|UserId" splitBy  "|"
fun removePair(e, keyToRemove) =
e match {
case is Array  -> e map removePair($, keyToRemove)
case is Object -> e mapObject (v, k) ->
if (keyToRemove contains(k as String) or keyToRemove contains(v as String))
                         {}
else
                          {(k): removePair(v, keyToRemove)}
else           -> e
 }
---
removePair(payload, keyToRemove)
```

Error:
`Cannot coerce String (queueNumber) to Boolean if (keyToRemove contains(k as String) or keyToRemove contains(v as String))`

How to enhance this function to also check and remove if any one of the given fields matches the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in the condition. First you should use parenthesis so the expression is evaluated in the correct order. Secondly -you haven't got yet this error because of the first one- you are trying to convert v to a String but when it is an array it is not possible to do that. So you should update the expression to something like:

```js
case is Object -> e mapObject (v, k) -> if ((keyToRemove contains (k as String)) or ((v is String) and (keyToRemove contains (v as String))))
```

Having said that you may want to consider using filterObject() in your script to remove unwanted members. This makes the intention of the transformation clearer and easier to understand:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json  

var keyToRemove = ["queueNumber","name","uniqueNumber","cur","UserId"]

fun removePair(e, keyToRemove) =
  e match {
    case is Array -> e map removePair($, keyToRemove)
    case is Object -> 
        e 
           filterObject ((v, k) -> !((keyToRemove contains (k as String)) or ((v is String) and (keyToRemove contains (v as String))))) 
           mapObject ($$):removePair($,keyToRemove)
    else -> e
  }
---
removePair(payload, keyToRemove)
```

Output (for input in the question):

```json
{
  "test": [
    {
      "objectName": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Update: added alternative solution with filterObject().

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, this is your input:

```
{
  "queueNumber": "123",
  "field": "name",
  "UserId": [
    12,
    12,
    34
  ],
  "test": [
    {
      "objectName": "test",
      "uniqueNumber": "123456"
    }
  ]
}
```

To remove a single property from an object the syntax is like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload -"field"
```

The result:

```
{
  "queueNumber": "123",
  "UserId": [
    12,
    12,
    34
  ],
  "test": [
    {
      "objectName": "test",
      "uniqueNumber": "123456"
    }
  ]
}
```

To remove multiple properties (array), this is the syntax:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload -- ["field", "test"]
```

The result:

```
{
  "queueNumber": "123",
  "UserId": [
    12,
    12,
    34
  ]
}
```

To remove a single nested property, it can be done like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun removePair(e, key) =
  e match {
    case is Array  -> e map removePair($, key)
    case is Object -> e mapObject (v, k) ->
                        if ((k as String) == key)
                          {}
                        else
                          {(k): removePair(v, key)}
    else           -> e
  }
---
removePair(payload , 'uniqueNumber')
```

The result:

```
{
  "queueNumber": "123",
  "field": "name",
  "UserId": [
    12,
    12,
    34
  ],
  "test": [
    {
      "objectName": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

To remove multiple nested properties use this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun removePair(e, key) =
  e match {
    case is Array  -> e map removePair($, key)
    case is Object -> e mapObject (v, k) ->
                        if (key contains (k as String))
                          {}
                        else
                          {(k): removePair(v, key)}
    else           -> e
  }
---
removePair(payload , ['uniqueNumber', "queueNumber"])
```

The result:

```
{
  "field": "name",
  "UserId": [
    12,
    12,
    34
  ],
  "test": [
    {
      "objectName": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```